# the third party service keep sending APIs and triggering the function many times

Tags: api, elixir, phoenix-framework

**We are using elixir;**
and I built a function called `receive_message`  this function receive API from third party service (360Dialog) this function contain another function call and if it success it will send 200 response; and if for any reason The inner function broke the response 200 will not been send.
My issue now :
The 3rd party API expects the 200 response right away, but if for any reason my inner function broke, I have no way to receive the API call one more time through a retry.
My original function looks like this

```
@spec receive_message(Plug.Conn.t(), map) :: Plug.Conn.t()
  def receive_message(conn, _params) do
  @spec deliver(%{:conversation => any, optional(any) => any}) :: maybe_improper_list
      Messenger.deliver(conn.assigns.message)
      send_resp(conn, 200, "")
  end
```

This created duplicate messages because 360dialog expects a 200 right away if it didn’t happen they keep sending retries.
i try to switch between  calling the message and sending the response like this

```
@spec receive_message(Plug.Conn.t(), map) :: Plug.Conn.t()
  def receive_message(conn, _params) do
      send_resp(conn, 200, "")
    enter code here
      @spec deliver(%{:conversation => any, optional(any) => any}) :: maybe_improper_list
      Messenger.deliver(conn.assigns.message)
  end
```

it work and there is no more duplicate messages
But i can't keep it like this because if Messenger.deliver Broke For any reason i want 360Dialg to retry again.
Any ideas how we can enhance this

Answer (score 0):

You have not shared the spec of `Messenger.deliver/1` so I cannot give an exact answer, but in general, functions usually report the success/error by returning a result of an operation. You need to check it and react accordingly. Somewhat alongside the following lines would work

```rb
def receive_message(conn, _params) do
  case Messenger.deliver(conn.assigns.message) do
    :ok -> send_resp(conn, 200, "")
    :error -> log_and_retry_or_skip
  end
end
```

In a case `Messenger.deliver/1` is async, it’d be more complex, you’ll need to await for the result, but the general pattern is above.

Comment: I built receive_message function; it is not phoenix-framework ; i edit the question and add the  spec for Messenger.deliver ; the issue that 360Dialog keep retrying until they receive 200  and keep triggering receive_message which make it execute many times  and cause me duplicate messages

Comment: What’s the difference between `Message.deliver/1` responses in cases of error vs. success? There must be some, som check the outcome and react respectively. The answer is still valid.